# How to send inline YouTube API into fullscreen on iOS?

Tags: ios, youtube

I have got the YouTube player on my webapp, it's inline, but I'd like to make it when you click a button it opens it into the full iOS player. I've tried using `webkitenterfullscreen` but it does nothing. 
The API is configured as such.

```
  var player;
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player1', {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      videoId: 'SOMEID',
        playerVars: {
          autoplay: 0,
          rel: 0,
          autohide: '1',
          disablekb: '1',
          controls: '1',
          html5:1,
          progressbar: false,
          modestbranding: '1',
          frameborder: '0',
          showinfo: '0',
          playsinline: '1',
      },
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }
```

Any help is much appreciated!
[image: See here]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set [`playsinline`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#playsinline) to 0 instead of 1.

Also note that you can, and should, pass numeric values as numbers instead of strings to be sure they are interpreted properly.

i.e. `showinfo: 0` not `showinfo: '0'`